# Does elementary has a signal which is emitted when object becomes visible after calling elm_naviframe_item_pop()?

Tags: c, tizen

I need to refresh screen because previous one has changed data in db, so the question: is there any way to know when the screen becomes visible again after previous was popped?

Answer (score 0):

well.. when pop is called, the top view will be started to go out. That means previous page is going to be visible again at the same time (just right 1 frame after).
I think, you can just regard the previous page will be visible on the time just right after calling elm_naviframe_item_pop();

Comment: Yeah, I know. But I have several pages which can change data, so I should put refresh code to every of them. But now I realized that user can just press back button, so the previous page should not be refreshed.